# Mobile Redirect via ModReWrite Simple code

Tags: mod-rewrite, mobile

is it possible to just use this simple code for the redirection of ALL mobile phones?

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*(iPad|iPhone|Mobile).* 
RewriteRule .* http://website.com/ [R]
```

since Android and Symbian and BB have **"Mobile"** in their strings.

or should the UserAgents be explicitly listed out like here:
http://www.projectronin.com/blog/?p=10

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If possible, redirect based on screen resolution or OS, not specific model of device. Keeping a model-specific list up to date is impossible.

Also, the above solution will *always* redirect them to the mobile site. Sometimes users want to use the full site on their mobile devices. For that reason, I would handle this in your site's code, not in htaccess.

Put something like this in your front controller, or a controller plug-in -- any bit of code that is executed on every page request in the non-mobile version/module of your site:

```
if(!isset($session->non_mobile)){ $session->non_mobile = false; }

if($_GET[non-mobile]){ $session->non_mobile = true; }

if(is_mobile_browser() && $session->non_mobile == false))
{
   header('location: http://m.yoursite.com');//redirect to mobile version
}
```